Command to pull in CD drive
I'd like to digitalize my CD collection. The quickest way to do this is to make a command that pulls in the CD drive, invokes abcde to rip and auto-eject the drive, and bind that command to a key. The only part needed to write that command that I don't know is what command can be used to pull in my CD drive automatically, basically an inverse of eject. Does anyone know such a command?

The inverse of eject is eject -t.

Side note: another great command is man 1 eject.

Thanks! I looked in the manual, but didn't see it. Should have read more carefully, I guess.

eject --help would also have given the command.
